# Flutter profiler build spikes without context

Tags: flutter, graph, profiler

I tried to profile the app I am working on and I noticed a lot of UI spikes which appear after starting or restarting the app.
They seem to last around a minute and then stop completely.

I tried using "Track Widget Builds" but the graph looks like this:
[image]

The little spikes seem to be "CollectNewGeneration" with "ParallelScavenge" and "IterateIsolateRoots" below, but I was not able to find anything about them.

Any idea how I can get to the bottom of this?